# как прописать в код такое действие? aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

прописал функцию которая проверяет является ли отправитель админом в чате и добавлен ли бот в админы другого канала или группы. И все вроде супер незнаю как сделать так чтобы если бот в другом канале или группе оказывался админом то в чате на указанную ссылку запускалась обязательная подписка с просьбой подписаться иначе вы не сможете писать для всех уча-ов в чате

````
async def is_admin(bot, message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    chat_member = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id, user_id)
    return chat_member.status in ['creator', 'administrator']

@dp.message_handler(commands=['sub'])
async def check_admin_status(message: types.Message):
    chat_link = message.text.split()[-1]  # Получаем ссылку из сообщения
    try:
        chat = await message.bot.get_chat(chat_link)  # Получаем объект чата по ссылке
        if await is_admin(message.bot, message):  # Проверяем является ли отправитель администратором
            chat_member = await chat.get_member(message.bot.id)  # Получаем информацию об участнике боте в чате
            if chat_member.status == 'administrator':
                await message.answer('Бот является администратором этого чата')
            else:
                await message.answer('Бот не является администратором этого чата')
        else:
            await message.answer('Вы должны быть администратором, чтобы выполнить эту команду')
    except ChatNotFound:
        await message.answer('Чат не найден')
    except Exception as e:
        await message.answer(f'Ошибка при проверке статуса администратора: {e}')```
````